# Search for partial match of text string in array and return match of greater length

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of locations, most of which contain a town name within them.  I would like to extract the town name.  However, some town names are contained within other names, for example, "hadley", and "east hadley".  Based on [this post](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2012/10/09/find-text-with-index-and-match/) , I have found 2 different almost-solutions to my problem (see image below).  However, depending on the order of the town names in Column D, the result may return the shorter or longer name.  How can I always obtain the more complete match?  I have over 18000 records so need an automated solution.

[Array formula in column B (top) and formula in column C (bottom)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQL3N.jpg)

Comment: Sort column D by length of name.  This will make the first formula work.  Because you are searching with wild cards as soon as it finds one it stops looking to see if there is one better.  In  E2  put `len(D2)` and copy down then sort only column D and E on E in Descending order.  So it bridgwater matches because of the wild cards in front and in back so it does not go on to find west bridgewater.  The second goes from the bottom up so it does the same.  You need to organize the search from longest to shortest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as per my comment,  The reason that neither formula is working has to do with the fact that excel searches one direction till it finds a match then stops searching, even if there is a better match further along.

Your first equation is searching from the top down and the second is searching from the bottom up, this is why you are getting different answers.

To fix this the search area must be put in some sort of order.  It must go from the longest string to the shortest along the search path.

To do this add a helper column in E.  Place the formula `Len(D2)` in E2 and copy down.  Then sort column D and E on Column E:

[image]

Then you just need to use the first equation:

[image]

If you like the second, sort columns D and E ascending:

[image]

And use the second equation:

[image]

The third option is to do both and take the longest but that is more steps that can be done quicker by simple sorting the search list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just compare the results of columns B and C in a new column for the greatest string with: `=IF(LEN(B2)>LEN(C2);B2;C2)`

Comment: that wont work the way he want it... cus the text depends on the order of his list (and may both hold the wrong value)

Answer (score 0):

just to give you a solution without sorting or helper-columns:

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$6,MAX((MAX(NOT(ISERROR((FIND($D$2:$D$6,A2)>0)))*LEN($D$2:$D$6))=LEN($D$2:$D$6))*NOT(ISERROR(FIND($D$2:$D$6,A2)))*ROW($1:$5)))
```

or a different(slight faster) way:

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$6,MAX((MIN(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,$D$2:$D$6,"")))=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,$D$2:$D$6,"")))*ROW($1:$5)))
```

however: i do not recommend using that... while it is okay for small tables, the time to calculate will incease extremely for each additional keyword...
also the first formula will output the first item in the list if no match is found, and the second formula will output the last entry of the list.

better use Scott Carner's solution with sorting by length (should be MUCH faster, but you may check that for yourself)

at least, you could also use vba like that:

```
Public Function maxMatch(str As String, rng As Range) As String
  Dim cell As Variant
  For Each cell In rng.Value
    If InStr(str, cell) > 0 And Len(cell) > Len(maxMatch) Then maxMatch = cell
  Next
End Function
```

and then simply put in the cell `=maxMatch(A2,$D$2:$D$6)`
(however, you where not going for VBA so that does not count) ;)